# Find when words appear next to each other in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a huge array of strings (words) that I'm analyzing for patterns.

I want to create a function to:

- Identify when words are appearing next to each other in a specific order more than once
- For each instance that the words appear in order, combine them into a single array element.

#### Example

Given the following array

```
let array = ["john", "smith", "says", "that", "a", "lock", "smith", "can", "open", "the", "lock", "unlike", "john", "smith"]
```

Desired Result:

```
["john smith", "says", "that", "a", "lock", "smith", "can", "open", "the", "lock", "unlike", "john smith"]
```

Ideally the function identifies more than just 2-word combinations (i.e. identifies when the combination of "white", "house", "press", "secretary" are appearing more than once.

I'm really struggling with the logic to have much to show. I've also been looking for a solution in a library like underscore.js without luck.

Comment: Are you looking for a logic regarding "Multiword Expression Identification"? If so, there are plenty of resources out there, but they are not that trivial unless you want it really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a "dictionary" of a all words and their immediate successor. Then loop through the original array and for each element, check if all dictionary returns match, and if so, combine the words and skip the immediate successor.

```js
var arr = ["john", "smith", "says", "that", "a", "lock", "smith", "can", "open", "the", "lock", "unlike", "john", "smith"];

function combineCommon(arr) {
  var dictionary = {};
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length - 1; a++) {
    var A = arr[a];
    if (dictionary[A] == void 0) {
      dictionary[A] = [];
    }
    dictionary[A].push(arr[a + 1]);
  }
  var res = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    var element = arr[index];
    var pass = false;
    if (dictionary[element].length > 1) {
      if (dictionary[element]
        .some(function(a) {
          return a != dictionary[element][0];
        }) == false) {
        pass = true;
      }
    }
    if (pass) {
      res.push(arr[index] + " " + dictionary[element][0]);
      index++;
    } else {
      res.push(arr[index]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(combineCommon(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this makes sense, and works perfectly when run in a jsfiddle. However, I'm having trouble incorporating it into my project. Is there some reason the above function wouldn't work in an es6 project?

Specifically, I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when it hits if (dictionary[element].length > 1) {...

Comment: @wrobbinz That happens when an undefined index is part of the array of words. The easiest way around this would be to use `Array.Filter` before looping.

Comment: I've boiled down the issue I'm having implementing this in my personal project to a new question on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105129/why-cant-this-function-process-this-particular-array

Answer (score 1):

You could count the pairs and check for pairs when reassembling the result.

```js
var array = ["john", "smith", "says", "that", "a", "lock", "foo", "bar", "baz", "smith", "can", "open", "foo", "bar", "baz", "the", "lock", "unlike", "john", "smith"],
    count = Object.create(null),
    result;

array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    var key = aa.slice(i, i + 2).join(' ');
    count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
});
result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
    var key = aa.slice(i, i + 2).join(' ');
    if (count[key] > 1) {
        a = key;
    } else if (count[aa.slice(i - 1, i + 1).join(' ')] > 1) {
        a = [];
    }
    return r.concat(a);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```js
var data = 
["john", "smith", "says", "that", "a", "lock", "smith", "can", "open", "the", "lock", "unlike", "john", "smith"]

var result= [];
var flag=0;
var n=data.length;
var k=0;

// Outer main for loop.
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
  // Get next word.
  next_word = data[i+1];

  
  flag=0;
    
  // Inner for loop.
  for(var j=0;j<n;j++){
    
    // john == john && smith == smith
    // smith == john && smith == smith 
    // ..
    // ..
    if(data[j]==data[i] && data[j+1]==next_word){
      flag++;
      temp_word = data[i]+' '+next_word;
    }
  }
    
  // If flag more than 1 that means same word sequence found more than one time.
  if(flag>1){
    result[k++]=temp_word; // Assign temp_word to result array. 
    i++; // increase outer loop by one so double entry we can restrict.
  }else{
    // If no sequence found then pass outer value to result value as it is.
    result[k++]=data[i];
  }

}

console.log(result);
```