# Why can't this function process this particular array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following function finds word pairs that appear more than once in an array, then combines them into a single array element. It works on the example array, but fails when I try to implement this into my project (which dynamically creates an array from scraping webpages).

**Function:**

```
function combineCommon(arr) {
  var dictionary = {};
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length - 1; a++) {
    var A = arr[a];
    if (dictionary[A] == void 0) {
      dictionary[A] = [];
    }
    dictionary[A].push(arr[a + 1]);
  }
  var res = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    var element = arr[index];
    var pass = false;
    if (dictionary[element].length > 1) {
      if (dictionary[element]
        .some(function(a) {
          return a != dictionary[element][0];
        }) == false) {
        pass = true;
      }
    }
    if (pass) {
      res.push(arr[index] + " " + dictionary[element][0]);
      index++;
    } else {
      res.push(arr[index]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(combineCommon(arr));
```

**Array that works:**

```
var arr = ["john", "smith", "says", "that", "a", "lock", "smith", "can", "open", "the", "lock", "unlike", "john", "smith"];
```

**Array that does NOT work:**

```
var arr = ['Social', 'care', 'fund', 'fails', 'to', 'reduce', 'pressure', 'on', 'hospital', 'beds', 'Court', 'questions', 'whether', 'US', 'travel', 'ban', 'is', 'anti', 'Muslim', 'Police', 'pay', 'out', 'at', 'least', '£195m', 'to', 'informants', 'in', 'five', 'years', 'Brexit', 'rebellion', 'avoided', 'after', 'meaningful', 'vote', 'offer', 'FA', 'reforms', 'Chairman', 'Greg', 'Clarke', 'to', 'quit', 'if', 'government', 'does', 'not', 'back', 'plans', 'Louisiana', 'tornadoes', 'The', 'whole', 'house', 'fell', 'apart', 'Uncertainty', 'over', '30', 'hours', 'free', 'childcare', 'say', 'councils', 'Uncertainty', 'over', '30', 'hours', 'free', 'childcare', 'say', 'councils', 'Hans', 'Rosling', 'Data', 'visionary', 'and', 'educator', 'dies', 'aged', '68', 'Dakota', 'Access', 'Pipeline', 'to', 'win', 'US', 'Army', 'permit', 'for', 'completion']
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj2q8dgq/2/) to demonstrate. Why does the second array not work?

Comment: You need to decide how to deal with the final word. If the input is `['john', 'smith', 'john', 'smith', 'john']` should the function return `['john smith', 'john smith', 'john']`, or should it not join any of the words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an off by one error when building the dictionary, which is causing the last word of the array not to be added to the dictionary. The first example works because the last word ("smith") is already included previously in the array.

The third line should be `for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {`, ie:

```
function combineCommon(arr) {
 var dictionary = {};
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    var A = arr[a];
    if (dictionary[A] == void 0) {
      dictionary[A] = [];
    }
    dictionary[A].push(arr[a + 1]);
  }
  var res = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    var element = arr[index];
    var pass = false;
    if (dictionary[element].length > 1) {
      if (dictionary[element]
        .some(function(a) {
          return a != dictionary[element][0];
        }) == false) {
        pass = true;
      }
    }
    if (pass) {
      res.push(arr[index] + " " + dictionary[element][0]);
      index++;
    } else {
      res.push(arr[index]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(combineCommon(arr));
```

Comment: On first glance, this seems to have resolved it. I'm going to stress test and follow up if I hit a hiccup. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't done undefined check at line number 18:

jsfiddle updated with below:

```
if (typeof dictionary[element] !== 'undefined' && dictionary[element].length > 1) {
      if (dictionary[element]
        .some(function(a) {
          return a != dictionary[element][0];
        }) == false) {
        pass = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is your solution more robust? Or is simply removing the `- 1` from line 7 as @dtkaias had proposed sufficient?